# Can Ubuntu 16.04 32/64-bit be installed in Pentium D

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 in the system

Configuration of the system

```
Memory -2Gb
Processor -Intel® Pentium(R) D CPU 2.80GHz × 2 
Graphics -Intel® 945G 
Disk Size -77Gb
```

Currently I have "Oracle Linux Server 7.2" 64-bit in this system, but it lags a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but Xubuntu 16.04 would be a better choice.

Comment: All our  *Ubuntu comes standard as live ISO's - so you can try it out, till you find the flavor that fits your hardware, and your preferences - so try!